# chromedriver and selenium-webdriver -> unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9515

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, selenium, webdriver

I wnat to run a ruby code with the selenium-webdriver on my raspberry pi. I've installed chromium-browser via apt-get. Ruby and selenium-webdriver are also installed. I've created a symlink for the chromedriver:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/chromium-browser /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

When i run my script, i get following:

```
unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9515
```

I've downloaded from the official page the 32bit version of the chromedriver for linux, bit of course doesn't work (`Exec format error - /usr/bin/chromedriver`).

Is there any way to compile the chromedriver instead to use the binary? Or has someone any idea how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my question, if it's possible to build only chromedriver from source, i get this link as answer:

http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/wiki/ContributingCode

The easier solution for me was a swich to firefox. So i've installed iceweasel and in the ruby script i'm using now `:firefox` instead `:chrome`.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to compile ChromeDriver for the arm6 architecture. Details can be found on [ChromeDriver's Internals](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/testing/webdriver-for-chrome/chromedriver-internals) site. You can also follow a similar guide "[Building Chromium OS for Raspberry Pi (ARMv6)](http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/04/19/building-chromium-os-for-raspberry-pi-armv6/)"

Comment: thanks, but i want to build only the chromedriver, not the full os. I'll contact the development team for that.